# Plugin "JetBrains Marketplace" is incompatible error while generating APK in Android Studio 4.1.3

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I am Getting this Error while generating APK in Android Studio 4.1.3

Plugin Error
Plugin "JetBrains Marketplace" is incompatible (since build 202.7660 > AI-201.8743.12).
Plugin "Gauge" is incompatible (since build 202.0 > AI-201.8743.12).
Plugin "Markdown" is incompatible (since build 202.6397 > AI-201.8743.12).

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle bat can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle clojure can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle coffeescript can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle cpp can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle csharp can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle css can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle docker can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle fsharp can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle git can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle go can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle groovy can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle handlebars can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle hlsl can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle html can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle ini can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle java can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle javascript can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle json can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle kotlin can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle less can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle log can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle lua can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle make can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle markdown-basics can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle mdx can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle objective-c can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle perl can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle php can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle powershell can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle pug can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle python can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle r can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle razor can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle ruby can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle rust can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle scss can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle search-result can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle shaderlab can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle shellscript can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle sql can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle swift can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle typescript-basics can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle vb can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle xml can't be registered

11:08 PM    TextMate bundle load error: Bundle yaml can't be registered

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the textMate Bundles [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7221-textmate-bundles/versions).
2. Then extract the folder[bundles] and put it in the your Android Studio's plugin folder. For example: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\textmate\lib.
3. Restart AndroidStudio, the error will disappear.